# Rails: How to acces @elements from new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

and thanks for Help!!

I´m Building my fisrt Rails app, and have this problem:

I made an Scaffold for a Class called "Expediente", from the index.html.erb I can gain acces over @expedientes but I cant do it from new.html.erb.

Here´s the code:

//index.html.erb, this run great:
.
.
.

```
    <% @expedientes.each do |expediente| %>

    <tr>
    <td class="custom"> <%= expediente.id %> </td>

    <td class="custom"> <%= expediente.tipo_expediente %> </td>

    <td class="custom">

<% expediente.pacientes.each do |paciente| %>

    <%= paciente.nombre_completo %><br/>
<% end %>
```

.
.
.

//new.html.erb, this doesnt works at all and sends undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass error message:

.
.
.

```
      <% @expedientes.each do |expediente| %>

      <%if expediente.individual?%>

      <% expediente.pacientes.each do |paciente| %>

     <option value=126><%= paciente.nombre_completo %></option>

     <%end%>

     <%end%>  

     <%end%>
```

.
.
.

Again thanks fot your Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the index action in your ExpedientesController (which renders the index.html.erb view) defines the variable `@expedientes`, but your new action (which renders the new.html.erb view) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your `New` action in the controller builds a single instance of your Expedientes class, therefore, it is not a collection you can iterate over with `each`.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the above 2 answers 
In you index method you might have something like

```
@expedientes = Expediente.all
```

in New method you would have

```
@expedient = Expediente.new
```

add this in your new method

```
@expedientes = Expediente.all
```

final

```
def new 
    @expedient = Expediente.new
   @expedientes = Expediente.all  
end
```